# WPML + Woocommerce Product 404 Page Error

Tags: http-status-code-404, woocommerce, product

http://profaj.org/armell/product/granul-dolum/  404 page

but other languages are working;

http://profaj.org/armell/en/product/granule-filling/

where is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

try this, I had the same problem and it worked for me:

1, WPML -> String Translation -> Search 'URL slugs -'

2, put the slug of your shop and products

3, Check 'Translation is complete' and click 'Save'

source: http://wpml.org/forums/topic/translated-woocommerce-product-category-slugs-broken-404-2/